# How to set up encrypted (fscrypt) /home on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: encryption, home-directory, 18.04

[Bionic Beaver Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)

> Other base system changes since 16.04 LTS:
>
> The installer no longer offers the encrypted home option using `ecryptfs-utils`. It is recommended to use full-disk encryption instead for this release.

[Launchpad Bug #1756840](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1756840)

---

How do I set up encrypted `/home` with fscrypt (ext4) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17863/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-is-now-released-and-posts-about-it-are-generall

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04