# Luks broken after update from 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 17.10, encryption, luks

I have a laptop with 17.10, with all updates.
It is using full disk encryption

I just did the update to 18.04 today.
All went well, it asked me to reboot at the end, so did I.

Upon boot, I was prompted for the luks passphrase, no way to get it successful.
The console tells me

```
No key available with this passphrase.
```

Thought it must have been an issue with kernel version.
Tested with a previous kernel, didn't help.

I've tested as well with both 18.04 and 17.10 live usb sticks with no more luck:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase /dev/sda5 --verbose --debug
# cryptsetup 1.7.3 processing "cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase /dev/sda5 --verbose --debug"
# Running command open.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating crypt device /dev/sda5 context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sda5 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load LUKS1 crypt type from device /dev/sda5.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.7.8) initialized in cryptsetup library version 1.7.3.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.13.0-21-generic x86_64.
# Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/sda5
# Key length 64, device size 498616320 sectors, header size 4036 sectors.
# Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
# Password retry count set to 3.
# Password verification disabled.
# Iteration time set to 2000 milliseconds.
# Checking volume  [keyslot -1] using [none] passphrase.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5: 
# Trying to open key slot 0 [ACTIVE_LAST].
# Reading key slot 0 area.
# Using userspace crypto wrapper to access keyslot area.
# Trying to open key slot 1 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 2 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 3 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 4 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 5 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 6 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 7 [INACTIVE].
No key available with this passphrase.
```

Followed this thread https://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2012-September/002735.html to check my luks header is healthy. Didn't find anything suspicious.

Of course I'm confident on the password.

Any hint on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try the answer to this question : [Ubuntu with full disk encryption - bad password after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031302/ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-bad-password-after-upgrade-to-18-04)

It worked for me.