# Bad password after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 with full disk encryption

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, password, encryption, luks

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 today and after a reboot, I noticed my password no longer works. I'm certain the password is correct, but I keep getting "bad passphrase or options". How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031302/ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-bad-password-after-upgrade-to-18-04 . The answer there helped me, but it was written in a cryptic way which took me a long time to figure out. Since you need 10 reputation to answer a question, I was unable to provide a better answer, hence asking it again here so I can answer it properly.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, as you say, I would suggest that you ask an mod to unprotect the question for you so you can add an answer... Or you could edit the answer to make it better. Duplicating the question seems like a poor choice

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do either. I'd obviously either edit the answer the in the duplicate, or post another answer if I could. I'm also answering this out of good will to help someone else. I don't have time to beg mods to unprotect questions etc.